# UICollectionView content not resizing properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview, autoresizingmask

I'm using a collection view inside of a static table view cell and I'm using autolayout to define the collection view's frame. Also, I'm using FlowLayout as the collectionViewLayout.

**The problem:**

- The behaviour is just as expected for the iPhone 4s and 5 screen. (same width)
- Once the width changes (iPhone 6 and 6 Plus), the collection view resizes properly, but the content keeps it size.
- This happens both for the cells and for the sections.

**Extra info:**

- I'm setting `collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex` to zero.
- The width of the cells is always being set to `tableView.frame.size.width / 2`
- Where I configure the layout:

  ```
  CGFloat headerHeight = 52;

  collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
  collectionViewLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.width, headerHeight);
  ```
- This is what it looks now. The green part represents the UICollectionView. Black and blue the cells. The dividing lines should be resizing and the cells should be divided in 2 columns.

[image]

Comment: Have you applied constraints to subviews inside your  custom collection view cell?

Comment: Where do you set the width for the cells? Are you using the collectionViewFlowLayout delegate method or something else?

Comment: @NileshMahajan Yes. Both for the cells and the section (which is a custom reusableView)

Comment: @CatalinaT. I've added the part where I configure the layout. I don't use any of the FlowLayout delegate methods, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code you posted, you are just setting the size for the header but I suppose you also have something like

```
collectionViewLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.width/2, height);
```

The important part is in which method you configure this, because if you do it in viewDidLoad the views are not correctly layouted yet so the width would just be the one set in the storyboard, no matter on which device you run your app.

The solution would be to place the code above in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    collectionViewLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.width/2, height);
    collectionViewLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.width/2, height);
}
```

Another way would be to implement the flowLayout delegate method:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return cCGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.width/2, CUSTOM_HEIGHT);
}

// The same for the header 
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return cCGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.width/2, CUSTOM_HEIGHT);
}
```

Make sure you set the delegate for the `collectionView`

Let me know how it goes :)

> **Update**

For the cells, add these methods too:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGRectZero;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}
```

As for the `sectionHeader`, maybe you need to check the constraints you have there, for the separator for example.

Comment: Thanks for the help Catalina. Unfortunately the content is keeping it's original size. I've tried both ways you've recommended. I will be posting a picture to better explain. :)

Comment: Are the delegate methods being called? You could add a `NSLog` there to print the `collectionView` frame, just to check that it is the correct one

Comment: They are being called and the return value in correct. :/

Comment: I have updated my answer with a new suggestion. The cells seem to have the correct size, I think the problem is the spacing between the items. For the header, maybe you can check the constraints again, or change it's background color to see the exact frame it has

Comment: That was it! Thanks Catalina! :)

Comment: That's awesome! Happy we could figure it out 

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use all the following for precise styling:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView;
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

To change the cell content size, use this:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake((kScreenWidth/2-8), 44); // Use your own X and Y sizes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attention. But this is not the answer for me. The content is keeping it's original size. Also, I'm already implementing the cell content size.